# Dojo - Tree in accordion is broken (while outside is ok) , Why?

Tags: dojo, dijit.tree

I've made simple application with dojo.
I took the exact same combo tree (cbtree) and put it once inside accordion and once first on page.

I don't understand why inside the accordion I get different cbTree (it looks really bad)
Here is online example of the problem :

```
http://77.235.53.170/cbTree/cbTree.htm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at your main.css, you have

```
#leftCol img {
     width: 100%;
}
```

Which overwrites

```
.dijitFolderOpened, .dijitIconFolderOpen, .dijitIconError {
    background-image: url("../../icons/images/commonIconsObjActEnabled.png");
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

You need resolve this in `main.css` by either removing your style, or changing it to a more specific rule; i.e. instead of `#leftCol img`, use `#leftCol .yourClass`.

Comment: Thx mate !!! How did you find it was the problem ? (so I'll know how/where to look for future ref.)

Comment: use developer console for browsers to inverstigate. For example, in google chrome, press ctrl+shift+i will trigger it. For firefox, you can install firebug add-in. For Ie8+, you can find a "developer tool" menuitem in menus.